# Drag-And-Drop-Methods won't fire

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a button and a stackpane. I now want to be able to drag that button onto that stackpane:

[image]

For testing purposes, I added all possible dragging events onto both components:

[image]

FXML:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.TestController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="source" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="172.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onDragDetected="#dragDetected" onDragDone="#dragDone" onDragDropped="#dragDropped" onDragEntered="#dragEntered" onDragExited="#dragExited" onDragOver="#dragOver" onMouseDragEntered="#mouseDragEntered" onMouseDragExited="#mouseDragExited" onMouseDragOver="#mouseDragOver" onMouseDragReleased="#mouseDragReleased" text="Drag Me!" />
      <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" layoutX="237.0" layoutY="110.0" onDragDetected="#dragDetected" onDragDone="#dragDone" onDragDropped="#dragDropped" onDragEntered="#dragEntered" onDragExited="#dragExited" onDragOver="#dragOver" onMouseDragEntered="#mouseDragEntered" onMouseDragExited="#mouseDragExited" onMouseDragOver="#mouseDragOver" onMouseDragReleased="#mouseDragReleased" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: lightgray;" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller:

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseDragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class TestController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button source;
    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }

    @FXML
    private void mouseDragEntered(MouseDragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("mouseDragEntered");
    }

    @FXML
    private void mouseDragExited(MouseDragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("mouseDragExited");
    }

    @FXML
    private void mouseDragReleased(MouseDragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("mouseDragReleased");
    }

    @FXML
    private void mouseDragOver(MouseDragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("mouseDragOver");
    }

    @FXML
    private void dragDetected(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragDetected");
    }

    @FXML
    private void dragEntered(DragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragEntered");
    }

    @FXML
    private void dragDone(DragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragDone");
    }

    @FXML
    private void dragExited(DragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragExited");
    }

    @FXML
    private void dragOver(DragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragOver");
    }

    @FXML
    private void dragDropped(DragEvent event) {
        System.out.println("dragDropped");
    }

}
```

When I drag and drop the button, only the `dragDetected`-function is fired. All following steps (i.e. `dragOver`, `dragDone` etc.) won't be recognized.

Comment: Have you attached any methods to the target node? https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/HelloDragAndDrop.java.html

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sedrick: Yes of course: "I added all possible dragging events onto **both** components"

Comment: See my next comment.

Comment: @Sedrick: There isn't much more code to add. Only the remaining DaD-methods, but they all follow the same structure.

Comment: Is the code you posted a `Minimal`, `Complete`, `Verifiable` example?

Comment: @Sedrick: Ok, I added all the code you need to reproduce my example.

Comment: For more information about mouse gestures see [the documentation of `MouseEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html). Note that `MouseDragEvent` corresponds with "_full press-drag-release_" and `DragEvent` corresponds with "_drag-and-drop_". However, those modes need to be activated, otherwise it defaults to "_simple press-drag-release_" which uses regular `MouseEvent`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putString(source.getText());
db.setContent(content);
event.consume();
```

to `dragDetected`.